# Wrong on login and restet pasword on LARAVEL 9

Tags: laravel, authentication, passwords, laravel-9

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x22kj.png)

Login is failed, the credencials email and password, is correct, but  laravel dont acces to dashboard

The password reset is worng to, the email is correct and i try chance of credentials on myphpadmin but dont entry.

this is my code

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests\Auth\LoginRequest;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class AuthenticatedSessionController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display the login view.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('auth.login');
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming authentication request.
     *
     * @param  \App\Http\Requests\Auth\LoginRequest  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function store(LoginRequest $request)
    {
        $request->authenticate();

        $request->session()->regenerate();

        return redirect()->intended(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
    }

    /**
     * Destroy an authenticated session.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function destroy(Request $request)
    {
        Auth::guard('web')->logout();

        $request->session()->invalidate();

        $request->session()->regenerateToken();

        return redirect('/');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're mass assignment while attempting authentication make sure the form requested keys must same as Model's $fillable keys.
then try this:

```php
     /**
     * Handle an incoming authentication request.
     *
     * @param  \App\Http\Requests\Auth\LoginRequest  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function store(LoginRequest $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->validated();

        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
           return redirect()->intended(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
        }
        return back()->with('message', 'The given credentials are not matched');
    }
```

if you're working with multi guards, try this:

```php
    public function store(LoginRequest $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->validated();

        if (Auth::guard('web')->attempt($credentials)) {
           return redirect()->intended(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
        }
        return back()->with('message', 'The given credentials are not matched');
    }
```

Comment: Hi Ahsan  thanks for answere, but the code dont acces to dashboard, only return on login page

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this example code from your and my implementation

```
<?php
    
    namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
    
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use App\Http\Requests\Auth\LoginRequest;
    use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Hash;
    use Session;
    use App\Models\User;
    
    class AuthenticatedSessionController extends Controller
    {
        /**
         * Display the login view.
         *
         * @return \Illuminate\View\View
         */
        public function create()
        {
            return view('auth.login');
        }
    
        /**
         * Handle an incoming authentication request.
         *
         * @param  \App\Http\Requests\Auth\LoginRequest  $request
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
         */
        public function store(LoginRequest $request)
        {
          $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required',
          ]);
    
        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            return redirect()->intended('dashboard')
                        ->withSuccess('Signed in');
        }
   
        return redirect("login")->withSuccess('Login details are not valid');
        }
    
        /**
         * Destroy an authenticated session.
         *
         * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
         */
        public function destroy(Request $request)
        {
           Session::flush();
           Auth::logout();
           return redirect('/');
        }
        /**
         * Registration page.
         *
         */
        public function registration()
        {
          return view('auth.registration');
        }
       
         /**
         * Store new user request handler
         *
         */
        public function storeUser(Request $request)
        {  
         $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:6',
         ]);
            
         $data = $request->all();
         $check = $this->create($data);
          
         return redirect("dashboard")->withSuccess('have signed-in');
        }
         /**
         * Store new user
         *
         */
        public function create(array $data)
        {
           return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password'])
           ]);
        }    
     
        /**
         * Dashboard for user
         *
         */
        public function dash()
         {
           if(Auth::check()){
            return view('dashboard');
            }
   
           return redirect("login")->withSuccess('are not allowed to access');
         }
    }
```

Please check from your project and check flash messages if password was wrong check password hashing correctly